# Drawing an outer shadow when drawing an image

Tags: android, android-canvas

I currently create a rounded version of an image in my app by drawing to a canvas. I would like to draw a faint outershadow around the image, but I cant quite get it right. I have 2 questions:
1. How can I draw an outer shadow (I can only seem to draw a shadow with a x or y offset)
2. How can I draw the shadow so that it does not have the artifacts shown in the attached image. Code:

```
![public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float cornerRadius) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth()+6, bitmap.getHeight() +6, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        int shadowRadius = getDipsFromPixel(3);
        final Rect imageRect = new Rect(shadowRadius, shadowRadius, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(imageRect);

        // This does not achieve the desired effect
        Paint shadowPaint = new Paint();
        shadowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        shadowPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        shadowPaint.setShadowLayer((float)shadowRadius, 2.0f, 2.0f,Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawOval(rectF, shadowPaint);

        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, imageRect, imageRect, paint);

        return output;
    }][1]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7DV6.png]

This is an example of the effect I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: @Leonidos I have attached an example now. You will notice a faint outer shadow around the image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here we go

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE42r.png]
Yup I still dig the Nexus S

First of all, please stop masking bitmaps that way, you can accomplish this without allocating another `Bitmap`, checkout [this blog post about how to draw rounded (and actually any shape) images](http://evel.io/2013/07/21/rounded-avatars-in-android/).

Second using that `Drawable` you probably can figure out how to add your shadow, just make sure it does not get clipped, on 18+ you could use `ViewOverlay`s for that, also keep in mind that [there are several unsupported drawing operations for hardware accelerated layers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported), that includes `setShadowLayer` and `BlurMaskFilter`, if performance is not an issue for you, you can disable it as always:

```java
if (SDK_INT >= HONEYCOMB) {
  view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

And use `setShadowLayer` as you were trying already:

```java
somePaint.setShadowLayer(shadowSize, deltaX, deltaY, shadowColor);
```

For a sample please check the link at the end.

If you still want to be hardware accelerated you will have to fake it at risk of overdrawing, you could use a radial gradient or draw another oval blurring it yourself (as mentioned before can't use `BlurMaskFilter`) or use a pre-blurred `Bitmap` (more masking).

For such a subtle shadow I would rather just go flat if performance is required, [the full sauce is in the banana stand](https://gist.github.com/eveliotc/6105241).

Update: [Starting L you can use real shadows](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/index.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and performance tip. Unfortunately I am new to Android so I find the outer shadow part very difficult. If you could please post the code showing how to create the outer shadow (See image I attached to the question) I will award you the bounty.

Comment: @RunLoop I've updated my answer, checkout the link at the bottom

Comment: @EvelioTarazona can you please post a sample about the shadow ? i know you've put a link, but please put some code here too.

Comment: @androiddeveloper makes sense, I prefer to use gist as GitHub's editor even for a simple edit is infinitely better than SO's, I've updated it indicating how to use `setShadowLayer`, hope that helps

Comment: @EvelioTarazona Hi, I am having some issues with the code. When I call getBitMap I still just get the original image. Is it possible to get a bitmap of the image after it has been rounded. Also, the shadow is not appearing

Comment: @RunLoop you have to `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` (or using shadow paint) for every view that will use it, read the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType(int%2C%20android.graphics.Paint), as said before if performance is an issue for you, don't use shadows or fake them by drawing something else, read carefully, `getBitmap` method always will return the original `Bitmap`, if you need a transformed `Bitmap` you can mask it as mentioned in blog post or just create a `Canvas` and call `draw` for that `RoundedAvatarDrawable`.

Comment: Hey good info @EvelioTarazona it was good to meet you at IO!! I'm personally trying to add a shadow to a bitmap in an AppWidget so sadly I don't think this approach will work though :/

Comment: Hey @schwiz nice to read you! interesting, will take a look at it when get some time, I guess for `RemoteView`s you will have the dirty way and draw to a second `Bitmap`

Comment: @EvelioTarazona yes, I think I can actually use the drawable class you wrote but it will still require a second bitmap because I have to create my own Canvas to draw on.

Comment: @EvelioTarazona This is what I've ended up with http://stackoverflow.com/a/24579764/384306

Comment: i have drawn shadow using your code - 
    somePaint.setShadowLayer(shadowSize, deltaX, deltaY, shadowColor);

now i want get shadow radius and shadow color,how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 39):

I wanted a similar effect, but on an AppWidget so unfortunately I couldn't use @EvelioTarazona's solution. This is what I came up with, it should work with a bitmap of any shape.

```
    final Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final Bitmap shadow = addShadow(src, src.getHeight(), src.getWidth(), Color.BLACK, 3, 1, 3);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    iv.setImageBitmap(shadow);
```

[image: Example with parameters size=3, dx=1, dy=3, color=BLACK]

```
 public Bitmap addShadow(final Bitmap bm, final int dstHeight, final int dstWidth, int color, int size, float dx, float dy) {
    final Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Config.ALPHA_8);

    final Matrix scaleToFit = new Matrix();
    final RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
    final RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, dstWidth - dx, dstHeight - dy);
    scaleToFit.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);

    final Matrix dropShadow = new Matrix(scaleToFit);
    dropShadow.postTranslate(dx, dy);

    final Canvas maskCanvas = new Canvas(mask);
    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    maskCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, scaleToFit, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
    maskCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, dropShadow, paint);

    final BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(size, Blur.NORMAL);
    paint.reset();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setMaskFilter(filter);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    final Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas retCanvas = new Canvas(ret);
    retCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0,  0, paint);
    retCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, scaleToFit, null);
    mask.recycle();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to post such answer, but the shadow color is not working hrer. Please suggest me.

Comment: @BalvinderSingh I'm happy to help if you want to post a gist or something with your issue. If you copy/paste my code exactly it should work just fine...

Comment: if I apply colorFilter on Image then Shadow appears in the color as I applied to image , But I want to add different color for shadow

Comment: @BalvinderSingh you would have to modify my code to do that but should be possible. You see you can pass a shadow color in now. Build the shadow layer like I do first then apply your color filter before building final image.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit to explain this process? specially the matrixes.

Comment: @Eddnav I'm doing basic Matrix Transforms, using the built in scale to fit center matrix to scale the bitmap to fit the dest height/width. The other matrix is moving the generated shadow image the dx/dy values. We are taking advantage of the built in linear algebra operations the framework offers with the matrices. The magic is the `setXfermode` call. I found this by trial and error, I have two overlapping images one with a slight dx/dy offset the xfer mode makes a new bitmap where they overlap.

Comment: If you want to use this in an AppWidget, use `remote_views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, shadow);` instead of `final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    iv.setImageBitmap(shadow);`

Comment: Could this be cached somehow to generate te shadow every frame without a frame-rate drop?

Comment: @rraallvv yes, same as caching any other bitmap

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
           ImageView imageView=findViewById(R.id.iv);
                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.images);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(doHighlightImage(icon));   


           public static Bitmap doHighlightImage(Bitmap src) {
                    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + 96, src.getHeight() + 96, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);
                    canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
                    Paint ptBlur = new Paint();
                    ptBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
                    int[] offsetXY = new int[2];
                    Bitmap bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(ptBlur, offsetXY);
                    Paint ptAlphaColor = new Paint();
                    ptAlphaColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmAlpha, offsetXY[0], offsetXY[1], ptAlphaColor);
                    bmAlpha.recycle();
                    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
                    return bmOut;
                }
```

Comment: how to add the shadow to the top and left sides also?

Answer (score 2):

**Create a xml name it round_shape.xml in drawable folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#bebebe" />
</shape>
```

Set this round_shape as back ground of image view like below

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_profile"
     android:layout_width="120dp"
     android:layout_height="120dp"
     android:padding="2dp"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/camera" />
```

The above code create a thin layer around image view after you have round the bitmap , below function will do this

```
public Bitmap roundBit(Bitmap bm) {

        Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(),
                bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bm, TileMode.CLAMP,
                TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
        c.drawCircle(bm.getWidth() / 2, bm.getHeight() / 2, bm.getWidth() / 2,
                paint);

        return circleBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my modification of sharmitha's answer. It's Kotlin and it uses the bmAlpha's size for the result Bitmap so that the shadow is not cropped.

```
private val metrics: DisplayMetrics by lazy {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    manager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
    metrics
}

private fun withDensity(value: Float): Float = metrics.density * value

private fun addShadow(src: Bitmap, blurRadius: Float, @ColorInt shadowColor: Int): Bitmap {
    val offsetXY = IntArray(2)
    val bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(
            Paint().apply { maskFilter = BlurMaskFilter(withDensity(blurRadius), BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL) },
            offsetXY
    )

    val bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmAlpha.width, bmAlpha.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    Canvas(bmOut).apply {
        drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
        drawBitmap(
                bmAlpha,
                0f,
                0f,
                Paint().apply { color = shadowColor })
        drawBitmap(
                src,
                0f - offsetXY[0].toFloat(),
                0f - offsetXY[1].toFloat(),
                null)
    }

    bmAlpha.recycle()

    return bmOut
}
```