# Adding a drop shadow to bitmap in android

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using Picasso to load a drawable into an image. I need to add a dropshadow to the bitmap I create and I am trying to accomplish this by adding a ShadowTransformation.

Using this 
[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24579764/2088117) I so far have this:

```
public class DropShadowTransformation implements Transformation {


    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setShadowLayer(12, 0, 0, Color.YELLOW);
        // Important for certain APIs
        paint.setShadowLayer(4,source.getWidth(),source.getHeight(),10);
        int[] offsetXY = new int[2];
        Bitmap shadowImage = source.extractAlpha(paint, offsetXY);
        Bitmap shadowImage32 = shadowImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        final Bitmap shadow = addShadow(shadowImage32, shadowImage32.getHeight(), shadowImage32.getWidth(), Color.BLACK, 3, 1, 3);


        Canvas c = new Canvas(shadow);
        c.drawBitmap(source, -offsetXY[0], -offsetXY[1], null);

        source.recycle();
        return shadowImage32;

    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "dropshadow";
    }

    public Bitmap addShadow(final Bitmap bm, final int dstHeight, final int dstWidth, int color, int size, float dx, float dy) {
        final Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

        final Matrix scaleToFit = new Matrix();
        final RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight());
        final RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, dstWidth - dx, dstHeight - dy);
        scaleToFit.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        final Matrix dropShadow = new Matrix(scaleToFit);
        dropShadow.postTranslate(dx, dy);

        final Canvas maskCanvas = new Canvas(mask);
        final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        maskCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, scaleToFit, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        maskCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, dropShadow, paint);

        final BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(size, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
        paint.reset();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setMaskFilter(filter);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

        final Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas retCanvas = new Canvas(ret);
        retCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0,  0, paint);
        retCanvas.drawBitmap(bm, scaleToFit, null);
        mask.recycle();
        return ret;
    }
```

}

and I use this in my gridview adapter

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(id).noFade().transform(new DropShadowTransformation()).resize(400,400).into(myImageView);
```

But despite trying several different flavours of the addShadow from google searches, I'm having no luck. The images DO display but there is no dropshadow whatsoever.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to add callback to your Picasso code -

```
.into(yourImageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        //here load shadow
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }
});
```