# Android - add a right shadow to a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to add a right shadow to a bitmap with this snippet of code below:

```
private static Bitmap drawBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Paint mShadow = new Paint();
    mShadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 40.0f, 0.0f, Color.RED);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0.0f, 0.0f, mShadow);
    return bm;
}
```

It appears not to be working, as a matter of fact, I m not seeing any shadow at all.

Please do you know why it is not working and a suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Please go through this StackOverflow answer: [Link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24579764/8892770)

Comment: @TarlanAhad I have already tried that and it didn't work for some unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw a rect before drawing your bitmap into the canvas, shadow layer and bitmap layers are separate layers and they need to be drawn one by one onto the canvas for the effect to be seen

```
    private static Bitmap drawBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Paint shadow = new Paint();

        shadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 40.0f, 0.0f, Color.RED);

        // Drawing shadow layer first before the bitmap
        canvas.drawRect((new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0)), shadow);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0.0f, 0.0f, shadow);

        return bm;
    }
```