# blurred bottom and right shadow for image view

Tags: android

How to add blurred right and bottom shadow for round corner image view with round corner shadow but I need blur effect for the below image ,Any one Suggest me how to achieve this ,Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: possible dublicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783467/drawing-an-outer-shadow-when-drawing-an-image

Comment: Thanks for sharing..