# How to set shadow effect on ImageView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, shadow

I'm tryin' to set shadow on an Image view on Xamarin.Forms (targeting the Android platform) and I got some examples on the internet.

The PCL code is quite simple, and the platform seemed pretty easy too. [The recipe available at the official xamarin developer site](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/passing-parameters/clr-properties/) is something like this:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyGroupName")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(LabelShadowEffect), "ShadowEffect")]
namespace MyWorkspace
{
    public class LabelShadowEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            try
            {
                var control = (Control as TextView); // TextView have the SetShadowLayer method, but others views don't

                var effect = (ShadowEffect)Element.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is ShadowEffect);
                if (effect != null)
                {
                    float radius = effect.Radius;
                    float distanceX = effect.DistanceX;
                    float distanceY = effect.DistanceY;
                    Android.Graphics.Color color = effect.Color.ToAndroid();
                    control?.SetShadowLayer(radius, distanceX, distanceY, color);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {               
            }
        }

        protected override void OnDetached() 
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

So I've noticed that this recipe works only for components that render with TextView (that's the only class with the `SetShadowLayer` method). In [other sources](http://xfcomplete.net/general/2016/01/20/using-effects/) I saw something more generic like:

```
public class ShadowEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached ()
    {
        Container.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 1;
        Container.Layer.ShadowColor = UIColor.Black.ToCGColor;
        Container.Layer.ShadowRadius = 6;
    }

    protected override void OnDetached ()
    {
        Container.Layer.ShadowOpacity = 0;
    }
}
```

By the use of `UIColor` I get that it's targeting iOS platform. No such a thing like this on Android views. I took a look at the XF FrameRenderer source code but I was not able to understand how they made the shadow effect works.

Someone can help me with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sadly there is no straight-forward way to get this working for android. But there are some options that you can try.

## Option #1

[There are several unsupported drawing operations for hardware accelerated layers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel#unsupported), that includes `SetShadowLayer` for non-text views.

So, in order to get the `SetShadowLayer` render for a non-text view, you need to set the `LayerType` rendering as `SOFTWARE` as explained in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914954/7292772).

```
SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
```

But the major drawback of course is that it can be a performance issue.

## Option #2

Second option is to use an radial gradient to emulate the shadow. I had implemented it as a renderer (but you should be able to implement it as an effect too). The result of course is not as great as a blurred shadow effect. You will also have to set the right `Padding` to let some space for the shadow to render, and be visible under the image.

```
protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
{
    try
    {
        var nativeCtrl = Control;
        var formsElement = Element;
        if (nativeCtrl == null || formsElement == null)
        {
            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        //convert from logical to native metrics if need be
        var shadowDistanceX = 10f;
        var shadowDistanceY = 10f;
        var shadowRadius = 5f;
        var shadowOpacity = .5f;
        var shadowColor = Color.Black;
        var cornerRadius = 0.2f;

        var bounds = formsElement.Bounds;

        var left = shadowDistanceX;
        var top = shadowDistanceY;
        var right = Width + shadowDistanceX;
        var bottom = Height + shadowDistanceY;

        var rect = new Android.Graphics.RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

        canvas.Save();
        using (var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint { AntiAlias = true })
        {
            paint.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);

            var nativeShadowColor = shadowColor.MultiplyAlpha(shadowOpacity * 0.75f).ToAndroid();
            paint.Color = nativeShadowColor;

            var gradient = new Android.Graphics.RadialGradient(
                0.5f, 0.5f,
                shadowRadius,
                shadowColor.ToAndroid(),
                nativeShadowColor,
                Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Clamp
            );
            paint.SetShader(gradient);

            //convert from logical to native metrics if need be
            var nativeRadius = cornerRadius;  
            canvas.DrawRoundRect(rect, nativeRadius, nativeRadius, paint);

            var clipPath = new Android.Graphics.Path();
            clipPath.AddRoundRect(new Android.Graphics.RectF(0f, 0f, Width, Height), nativeRadius, nativeRadius, Android.Graphics.Path.Direction.Cw);
            canvas.ClipPath(clipPath);
        }
        canvas.Restore();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log exception
    }

    base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```

## Option #3

Another option would be to use [SkiaSharp for Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Views.Forms/) - i.e. create a container (or layered) view that renders the shadow around the child view (image). You can either have SkiaSharp render the image too, or embed a XF based image control inside the layout.

```
protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    var imgInfo = args.Info;
    var surface = args.Surface;
    var canvas = surface.Canvas;

    var drawBounds = imgInfo.Rect;
    var path = new SKPath();
    var cornerRadius = 5f;

    if (cornerRadius > 0)
    {
        path.AddRoundedRect(drawBounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
    }
    else
    {
        path.AddRect(drawBounds);
    }

    using (var paint = new SKPaint()
    {
        ImageFilter = SKImageFilter.CreateDropShadow(
                                        offsetX,
                                        offsetY,
                                        blurX,
                                        blurY,
                                        color,
                                        SKDropShadowImageFilterShadowMode.DrawShadowOnly),
    })
    {
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!All those options looks very promising.I'll decide which one it the best for each need later, but it is really kind of solution that I was expecting for.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please try this below code will work

```
<Frame OutlineColor="Transparent" Padding="0" CornerRadius="0" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Teal">
    <Image Source="Imagename" Aspect="Fill" />
</Frame>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I'll make a try and let you know.

Comment: As I thought, it was just an image inside a frame, no shadow effect was attached to the image, but thanks anyway

Comment: Frame default provided shadow effect and its working so once try it and let me know

Comment: Yes, it do. But this shadow is under a rectangle shape of the frame (with or without roudend corners.  I need the shadow in the image's shape

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `Elevation` property instead of `ShadowLayer`; Android will add the correct shadow itself based on the elevation you give, and it will adhere to Material Design.

Though you will have to use a custom renderer for this approach, and will need to create a different renderer for iOS/UWP.

Comment: I'ld like to set the shadow color too...  but I'll make try and let you know

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Ah, the `Elevation` property doesn't allow you to customize the shadow color unforutnately.

Comment: I've tested the elevation thing but the effect is too soft and I haven't too many options to customize it =/. Thank you very much for check